# How to retrieve top n children of each node in a tree in one query

Tags: database, neo4j, orientdb, arangodb

I am recently evaluating graph databases or any other databases on one specific requirement:

The ability to retrieve top n children of each node by a aggregated property of the node's direct children and their all direct and indirect children in a tree in one query. The result should return correct hierarchical structure.

Example

```
root + 11
          ++ 111
             ++ 1111
          ++ 112
             ++ 1121
             ++ 1122
             ++ 1123
          ++ 113
     + 12
          ++ 121
          ++ 122
             ++ 1221
             ++ 1222
             ++ 1223
          ++ 123
     + 13
         ++ 131
         ++ 132
         ++ 133
         ++ 134
     + 14
```

`Each node has a property of how many direct children it has. And the tree has no more than 8 levels`. Let's say I want to run a query of the entire tree, by all nodes at each level, whose top 2 children which has the most direct and indirect children.  It would give us the following:

```
root + 11
          ++ 111
             ++ 1111
          ++ 112
             ++ 1121
             ++ 1122
     + 12
          ++ 121
          ++ 122
             ++ 1221
             ++ 1222
```

I am wondering if there is any graph database, or any other database that support such query efficiently and if yes, how ?

Answer (score 1):

**Using Neo4j**

You can do this with Neo4j, but you'll need to ensure you're using the [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) plugin for access to some of the map and collection functions and procedures.

One thing to note first. You didn't define any criteria to use when selecting between child nodes when there is a tie between their descendent node counts. As such, the results of the following may not match yours exactly, as alternate nodes (with tied counts) may have been selected. If you do need additional criteria for the ordering and selection, you will have to add that to your description so I can modify the queries accordingly.

**Create the test graph**

First, let's create the test data set. We can do this through the Neo4j browser.

First let's set the parameters we'll need to create the graph:

```
:param data => [{id:11, children:[111, 112, 113]}, {id:12, children:[121, 122, 123]}, {id:13, children:[131,132,133,134]}, {id:14, children:[]}, {id:111, children:[1111]}, {id:112, children:[1121, 1122, 1123]}, {id:122, children:[1221,1222,1223]}]
```

Now we can use this query to use those parameters to create the graph:

```
UNWIND $data as row
MERGE (n:Node{id:row.id})
FOREACH (x in row.children |
 MERGE (c:Node{id:x})
 MERGE (n)-[:CHILD]->(c))
```

We're working with nodes of type :Node connected to each other by :CHILD relationships, outgoing toward the leaf nodes.

Let's also add a :Root:Node at the top level to make some of our later queries a bit easier:

```
MERGE (r:Node:Root{id:0})
WITH r
MATCH (n:Node)
WHERE NOT ()-[:CHILD]->(n)
MERGE (r)-[:CHILD]->(n)
```

The :Root node is now connected to the top nodes (11, 12, 13, 14) and our test graph is ready.

**The Actual Query**

Because the aggregation you want needs the count of all descendants of a node and not just its immediate children, we can't use the child count property of how many direct children a node has. Or rather, we COULD, summing the counts from all descendants of the node, but since that requires us to traverse down to all descendants anyway, it's easier to just get the count of all descendants and avoid property access entirely.

Here's the query in its entirety below, you should be able to run the full query on the test graph. I'm breaking it into sections with linebreaks and comments to better show what each part is doing.

```
// for each node and its direct children, 
// order by the child's descendant count
MATCH (n:Node)-[:CHILD]->(child)
WITH n, child, size((child)-[:CHILD*]->()) as childDescCount
ORDER BY childDescCount DESC
// now collect the ordered children and take the top 2 per node
WITH n, collect(child)[..2] as topChildren

// from the above, per row, we have a node and a list of its top 2 children.
// we want to gather all of these children into a single list, not nested
// so we collect the lists (to get a list of lists of nodes), then flatten it with APOC
WITH apoc.coll.flatten(collect(topChildren)) as topChildren

// we now have a list of the nodes that can possibly be in our path
// although some will not be in the path, as their parents (or ancestors) are not in the list
// to get the full tree we need to match down from the :Root node and ensure
// that for each path, the only nodes in the path are the :Root node or one of the topChildren
MATCH path=(:Root)-[:CHILD*]->()
WHERE all(node in nodes(path) WHERE node:Root OR node in topChildren)

RETURN path
```

Without the comments, this is merely an 8-line query.

Now, this actually returns multiple paths, one path per row, and the entirety of all the paths together create the visual tree you're after, if you view the graphical results.

[image]

**Getting the results as a tree in JSON**

However, if you're not using a visualizer to view the results graphically, you would probably want a JSON representation of the tree. We can get that by collecting all the result paths and using a procedure from APOC to produce the JSON tree structure. Here's a slightly modified query with those changes:

```
MATCH (n:Node)-[:CHILD]->(child)
WITH n, child, size((child)-[:CHILD*]->()) as childDescCount
ORDER BY childDescCount DESC
WITH n, collect(child)[..2] as topChildren
WITH apoc.coll.flatten(collect(topChildren)) as topChildren
MATCH path=(:Root)-[:CHILD*]->()
WHERE all(node in nodes(path) WHERE node:Root OR node in topChildren)
// below is the new stuff to get the JSON tree
WITH collect(path) as paths
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths) YIELD value as map
RETURN map
```

The result will be something like:

```
{
  "_type": "Node:Root",
  "_id": 52,
  "id": 0,
  "child": [
    {
      "_type": "Node",
      "_id": 1,
      "id": 12,
      "child": [
        {
          "_type": "Node",
          "_id": 6,
          "id": 122,
          "child": [
            {
              "_type": "Node",
              "_id": 32,
              "id": 1223
            },
            {
              "_type": "Node",
              "_id": 31,
              "id": 1222
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_type": "Node",
          "_id": 21,
          "id": 123
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_type": "Node",
      "_id": 0,
      "id": 11,
      "child": [
        {
          "_type": "Node",
          "_id": 4,
          "id": 111,
          "child": [
            {
              "_type": "Node",
              "_id": 26,
              "id": 1111
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_type": "Node",
          "_id": 5,
          "id": 112,
          "child": [
            {
              "_type": "Node",
              "_id": 27,
              "id": 1121
            },
            {
              "_type": "Node",
              "_id": 29,
              "id": 1123
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```